# Grails 3 and asset pipeline - assetResourceLocator exception

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline, grails-3.0

In my Grails 3.1.11 application I have so far used successfully the asset pipeline for all my javascript and css files.

Now I need to get one js file among my assets, and to do so I'm using the `assetResourceLocator` bean. Here's my controller:

```
class MyController {

    def assetResourceLocator

    def index() {
        Resource res = assetResourceLocator.findAssetForURI('myResource.js')
        println res.contentLength()
        println res.file
    }

}
```

`res` is not null, and its content length is returned correctly. But `res.getFile()` throws `FileNotFoundException: Byte array resource [resource loaded from byte array] cannot be resolved to absolute file path`.

It's not a blocking issue for me, as i was able to get a `File` using `res.inputStream`, but I'm wondering why such exception occurred.

As a side note, other methods like `res.getURI()` and `res.getURL()` throw the same exception.

I'm using asset pipeline v. 2.11.1, though I get the very same result even downgrading up to 2.8.2.

Comment: just curious, why are you trying to load a js file in a controller? Can you not use <asset:javascript src="myResource.js"/> in your gsp file?

Comment: You're absolutely right :) But then I'm using Nashorn to evaluate the js file..

Comment: So I am assuming you want to grab the file contents and use it the way you like it, then why not just use plain old java.io.File class.

Comment: have you found any solutin for this problem. I have exact problem and couldn't resolve it

Comment: @trd3v3lop The issue is still occurring up to Grails 3.2.6 (I'll be able to test it with Grails 3.3 soon), but as I wrote in the question I used `res.inputStream` as workaround to get a File.  Actually later, refactoring my code, I was able to use the inputStream directly, maybe you can do the same without writing to a file

Comment: rather than the file I need the path of it. I use 3.3 and it doesn't work either.